# Pass static method stored in string in c#

Tags: c#, methods, reference, delegates, static-methods

How can I pass the static method with params which are stored in a string? I want to use method from another class with params. I have a dictionary depending on what folder which function should be used. 
Here is main class:

```
foreach (string folder in folders)
  {
    foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder))
     {
        //switch (folder)
        //{
        //}
      foreach(var a in GetDictionaryToFunction())
      {
       string nameFolder = folder.Split('\\')[folder.Split('\\').Count() - 1];
       if (a.Key == nameFolder)
        {
        //And here I want to use the specified method with file path as param.
          Type thisType = this.GetType();
          MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod(a.Value);// +"("+ file + ")");
          theMethod.Invoke(theMethod, null);
         }
       }
  }
```

And I'm trying to use function from this class:

```
class File
{
    public static void ReadPayments(string filePath)
    {
        string[] rows = Reader.ReadCsv(filePath);
        if (rows.Count() == 0) return;

        listPlatnosci.Clear();
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

        foreach (string row in rows)
        {
            TransformRow(row, fileName);
        }
    }
```

example dictionary: <folder, FunctionToAddValues>

Comment: I don't know how your classes are designed, so I don't really see what's the problem here,, but you could just add arguments to that static method. ```public static MyMethod(string arg) { ... }``` and then call in your snippet ```MyClass.MyMethod(filePath)```

Comment: Problem is that this "theMethod" returns null. I don't know if it is because I'm trying to use function from another class.

Comment: Can you put all the class? There is not enough information in your snippet.

Comment: Okey, I extended snippets what do you think right now?

Comment: Don't need to pass param casue already have it in string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReadPayments should be define as follow:

```
public class ClassWithTheMethod
{
    public static void ReadPayments(string folder)
    {
        //Whatever
    }
}
```

And call it by using this:

```
MethodInfo theMethod = typeof(ClassWithTheMethod).GetMethod(a.Value, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, null, new Type[] { typeof(string) }, null);
theMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { a.Key }); //null for static methods
```

Comment: Still "theMethod" have null value

Answer (score 0):

Here is code which worked for me:

```
MethodInfo theMethod = typeof(File).GetMethod(a.Value, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, null, new Type[] { typeof(string) }, null);
                            theMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { file });
```